# Transitive group action with transitive subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I want to prove the following:

Assume $G$ acts transitively on $\Omega$, and $H \leq G$ is a transitive subgroup. Show that for $\alpha \in \Omega, G=HG_\alpha$.

This is what I have so far:

Let $\alpha \in \Omega$.

Let $G_\alpha$ denotes the stabilizer of $\alpha$ in $G$, and $O_G(\alpha)$ denotes the orbit of $\alpha$ in $G$.

Clearly, $HG_\alpha\subseteq G$. So, we only need to show that $G \subseteq HG_\alpha $.

Let $g \in G$. As $H$ acts transitively on $\Omega,$ we have $ O_H(\alpha)=\Omega.$   Hence, $\alpha g=\alpha h$ for some $h \in H.$

So, $\alpha g h^{-1}=\alpha$. Thus, $g h^{-1} \in G_\alpha.$ Let $k=g h^{-1}.$ Hence, $g=kh \in G_\alpha H.$

But I want to say $g \in HG_\alpha.$ Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're fine.  Your next step is $G=G^{-1}=(G_{\alpha}H)^{-1}=H^{-1}{G_{\alpha}}^{-1}=HG_{\alpha}$, and you have what you want.

Comment: By $G^{-1}$, do you mean this $G^{-1}=\{ g^{-1} : g \in G \}$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.